# Refuse to apply style from lightning style bundle bcauz it's MIME type(html/css) is nt a supported style sheet

Tags: lightning-aura-components, css

I'm new to salesforce lightning & trying to make responsive design
by media queries like this

```
@media  all and (max-width : 1280px) 
{
 .THIS .columngap {    
     color : red;
    }
}

div class="columngap">
     Contact Us
 </div>
```

it's nt showing angular bracket

so I keep getting error in inspect that mime type is nt supported &
**strict MIME checking is enabled**
SO can anyone pls tell me how can i resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

In Aura, to target a top-level element with CSS, you specifically need to *not* include a gap between `.THIS` and the next class. In other words, your CSS was wrong, it should read:

```
@media  all and (max-width : 1280px) 
{
 .THIS.columngap {    
     color: red;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi There, I tried your way and didn't give any gap but it is  still nt workin.

Comment: @Rahultiwari I don't think we have enough information to help you, then. It works in my org...